# Jackson custom serializer

Tags: jackson, serialization

I try to use a custom Jackson serializer, but unfortunately the serializer will not be triggered.

In my Application I added Jackson:

```
JacksonJaxbJsonProvider jacksonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
jacksonProvider.setMapper( mapper );
s.add( jacksonProvider );
return s;
```

I added a serializer for my class TestType:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = TestSerializer.class)
public class TestType {
  private String test;

  public String getTest(){
    if (test==null || test.isEmpty()){
      test="test";
    }
    return test;
  }

  public void setTest(String test) {
    this.test = test;
  }
}

public class TestSerializer extends JsonSerializer<TestType> {
  @Override
  public void serialize(TestType value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      jgen.writeStartObject();
      jgen.writeStringField("special serialization", value.getTest());
      jgen.writeEndObject();
  }
}
```

The API:

```
@GET 
@Produces({"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
public Response getTest(@HeaderParam( RestHelper.HEADER_PARAM_ORIGIN ) String origin, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpHeaders headers) {
   TestType test = new TestType();
   test.setTest("test");
   return Response.status(200).entity( test ).build();
}
```

Did I miss any step to register the serializer?

Regards,
hyperion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks ok. Just makes sure you are using Jackson 2.x annotations (`com.fasterxml.jackson`) with Jackson 2.x `ObjectMapper`. Since annotation names of 1.x are the same (but Java package differs), they will not work, despite looking identical (only `import` statement in sources differing).

Note, too, that you can implement `JsonSerializable` which would remove the need to use `@JsonSerialize` annotation here.